# How to re format GetVertices to return (x1,y1,0), (x2,y2,0), (x3,y3,0);?

Tags: java

So, I have added a constructor that makes it possible to create triangles with the expression
new Triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) where (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) are the three
vertices of the triangle. However, I need to make getVertices return (x1,y1,0), (x2,y2,0), (x3,y3,0); that is, the coordinates
given to the constructor, with coordinate z set to 0.

below is code for a triangular prism, im trying to shorten/reformat so it works for a triangle, with a different formula.

```
 private List<Point> getVertices() {
        List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new Point(x1 + x, y1 + y, z - height / 2.0));
        result.add(new Point(x2 + x, y2 + y, z - height / 2.0));
        result.add(new Point(x3 + x, y3 + y, z - height / 2.0));
        result.add(new Point(x1 + x, y1 + y, z + height / 2.0));
        result.add(new Point(x2 + x, y2 + y, z + height / 2.0));
        result.add(new Point(x3 + x, y3 + y, z + height / 2.0));
        return result;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Point is a 2 dimensional coordinate of `x and y`.  You would need to define your own class for a 3 dimensional `x,y,z`.  Call the class `Point3D`

```
class Point3D {
   int x, y, z;
   public Point3D (int x, int y, int z) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.z = z;
  }
  public int getX() {
      return x;
  }
 public int getY() {
      return y;
  }
 public int getZ() {
      return z;
  }
}
```

That is not difficult but your `List<Point3D>` may not be compatible with something that expects `List<Point>` so you need to consider that.

You could also subclass the `Point` class. But there are quite a few methods you would need to add if you wanted the same functionality for a 3D point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so this means I would have to return three point3Ds for the triangle then?

Comment: It would still require six 3D points for a triangular prism.  They describe each triangular end separated by some distance. One possibility is for some length `k` the first 3 points would denote a triangle at some location `z`.   The other end of the prism could be at those same `x and y` points with that `z` set to `z  + k`. But there are an infinite number of possibilities with the prism ending up being rotated, depending on the choice of coordinates.